# Convert timestamp to date in Oracle 19c without time

Tags: date, casting, timestamp, oracle19c

I'm coming from db2 and now need to cast a timestamp field to date in Oracle 19c.

Using cast(mytimestampfield as date) it is returning the time too.
How to that without return the time?

Testing...it returns *2024-02-28 13:16:42*

```
SELECT cast(SYSTIMESTAMP as date) FROM dual;
```

I'm looking for : *2024-02-28*

Comment: An Oracle date always has time components. You can set those to midnight (with `trunc()`) but you can't get rid of them completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you can use truncate:

```
TRUNC(cast(SYSTIMESTAMP as date))
```

See the Oracle documentation for more information

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TRUNC-date.html#GUID-BC82227A-2698-4EC8-8C1A-ABECC64B0E79

Comment: That still has a time - it's just set to midnight now. That might be good enough for the OP's needs though...

Comment: Are you sure? I cannot test it at the moment, but in the Live SQL environment it looked right: [Oracle Live SQL](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/docs/sqlrf/trunc/trunc-dates.html)

Comment: Yes. Statement 4 in your examples shows the time as 00:00, not absent. ALso [from the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-5405B652-C30E-4F4F-9D33-9A4CB2110F1B): "For each DATE value, Oracle stores the following information: year, month, day, hour, minute, and second." They may be zero but they're always there.

Comment: Yes, the time component is always there. But I think he just wants to be able to select it without the time being shown. In step three, the `nls_date_format` for the session is changed. With the default Oracle configuration, the time should not be displayed. 

But if the time is still displayed, you can change it with `ALTER SESSION SET nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD'`.

Comment: No, it won't be displayed, but it will still be there. If you're relying on how it's displayed then it doesn't matter if the time is 00:00:00 or 13:16:42. If you're using that date value as an actual date, not a string, then the time is there and matters. (And the OP does seem to be doing that, or they wouldn't need to cast to date, they could format the timestamp as a string for display.) But again, just truncating the date to midnight might solve the OP's actual problem. <shrug>

Comment: If you are using `TRUNC` then you do not need to use `CAST` as well - `TRUNC` always returns a `DATE` (and, as mentioned, will always have a time component).

Comment: The problem arose when I needed to perform a group by using only the date for a timestamp field. I needed to group by date, without the time. And I was already used to using db2 without any problems for similar queries.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, a `DATE` is a binary data-type that consists of 7 bytes representing: century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second. It **ALWAYS** has those 7 components and it is **NEVER** stored in any particular human-readable format.

> How to that without return the time?

Since a `DATE` always has those 7 components then it always has a time component.

If you want to set the time to midnight then use `TRUNC`:

```sql
SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP, TRUNC(SYSTIMESTAMP) FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| SYSTIMESTAMP | TRUNC(SYSTIMESTAMP) |
| --- | --- |
| 2024-02-28 19:12:18.242271 +00:00 | 2024-02-28 00:00:00 |

If you want to **display** a date in the format `YYYY-MM-DD` then you can use `TO_CHAR`:

```sql
SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP, TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM DUAL;
```

Which outputs the value as a string:

| SYSTIMESTAMP | TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP,'YYYY-MM-DD') |
| --- | --- |
| 2024-02-28 19:14:23.533246 +00:00 | 2024-02-28 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hFay3g8I)